# jQuery tooltip is not displayed anymore after updating table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a table with a single span element in td.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="td">
                <span id="span1">this is span1</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I create a jQuery tooltip for span1.

```
$('#span1').tooltip({
    content: function(){
        return "tooltip_span1";
    },
    items: $('#span1')
});
```

I update the content of td adding a second span with id 'span2' by concatenating.

```
var tdHtml = $('#td').html();
tdHtml+="<br> <span id=\"span2\">this is span2</span>"
$('#td').html(tdHtml);
```

I add a tooltip for span2 which will be displayed correctly.

```
$('#span2').tooltip({
    content: function(){
        return "tooltip_span2";
    },
    items: $('#span2')
});
```

However, the tooltip of span1 is not displayed anymore after updating the td content. Why?

Please see a jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pete80/dy7pq/1/).

Thanks very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use append, right now you are deleting and re-adding span1 (and removing previously added behavior)

```
$('#td').append("<br> <span id=\"span2\">this is span2</span>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dy7pq/2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you are treating the existing code as HTML and that the DOM reference is lost. It will work if instead you append a DOM fragment.

```
var newSpan = $('<span id="span2">this is span2</span>');
$('#td').append(newSpan);
```

See this fiddle for complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/b3xGM/1/